# Iphone/ipad background image

Tags: iphone, ipad, image, background

So I've followed this guide to putting a background to my main window http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/03/how-to-add-a-nice-background-image-to-your-grouped-table-view/

However, I am using a navigation controller, and when I push the navigation view(s) on the stack, the new views cover it (obviously). But I change all of the background colors of the navigation views to clear, but it still doesn't show the original view.

I'd like the background image to be there for the whole program. How can I do so while using the navigation controller and without having to create a new image for each subsequent view.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the idea of setting the background to the navigation controller and then making the new ViewControllers in that stack be transparent can work. But I would create a singlelton UIImageView that would always be there and then on each onLoad just add it and make it be on the back of everything.

I would recommend following this pattern for the [singlelton](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/)

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following for all of your view controllers before pushing or adding

```
yourViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```